# How to do git pull through build.xml (ant task)

Tags: git, ant, build.xml

Here, i am trying to pull a file from git if it not present in the local folder, here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="deploy">

    <target name="deploy" depends="file-checks, local-file, git-file"/>

    <target name="file-checks">
       <available file="C:\Users\Hareesh\Desktop\H2H\conf\rdbms1.properties"  property="file.found"/>
    </target>

    <target name="local-file" if="file.found">
        <echo message="File is available in Local" />
    </target>
    <target name="git-file" unless="file.found">
        <echo message="No" />
        <git command = "clone">
            <args>
                <arg value = "git://github.com/280north/ojunit.git" />
                <arg value = "ojunit" />
            </args>
        </git> 
    </target>
</project>
```

it is showing below error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Hareesh\Desktop\H2H\conf\build.xml
file-checks:
local-file:
git-file:
     [echo] No

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Hareesh\Desktop\H2H\conf\build.xml:15: Problem: failed to create task or type git
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


Total time: 203 milliseconds
```

I have followed below URL:
http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2008/11/ant-tasks-for-git/

is there any mistake in arg values?? am not able to find as i don't have knowledge on git commands...Please help me..Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking the provided link, the author has defined `git` as a macrodef. So you need to include these definitions in your buildfile, otherwise Ant won't recognize what `git` is:

```
<macrodef name = "git">
    <attribute name = "command" />
    <attribute name = "dir" default = "" />
    <element name = "args" optional = "true" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message = "git @{command}" />
        <exec executable = "git" dir = "@{dir}">
            <arg value = "@{command}" />
            <args/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name = "git-clone-pull">
    <attribute name = "repository" />
    <attribute name = "dest" />
    <sequential>
        <git command = "clone">
            <args>
                <arg value = "@{repository}" />
                <arg value = "@{dest}" />
            </args>
        </git>
        <git command = "pull" dir = "@{dest}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Ok, can i directly include this macrodef under "git-file" target

Comment: @HarithaR Yes you can include the macrodef in the target, but adding it as a top-level element outside would make it visible to all targets in case some other target wants to use it as well.

Comment: Now i have corrected my method and sending correct values, but it is throwing an exception like below: `C:\Users\Haritha\Desktop\H2H\conf\build.xml:23: The directory C:\Users\Haritha\Desktop\H2H\conf\https:\github.com\libgit2\libgit2.git does not exist` , am sending input https:\github.com\libgit2\libgit2.git but windows path is getting added, how to solve this issue

Comment: @HarithaR Please ask this in a different question specifying the updated buildfile and the exact error.